# How to change position of item in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on an Android app which has a recycler view. I have items ordered randomly in the recycler view. I want to move the fifth item of the list to the first position. And move the item previously at the first position to second position. Can anybody help me with this please?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**`Collections.swap()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int))

- `Swaps` the elements at the specified positions in the specified list. (If the specified positions are equal, invoking this method leaves the list unchanged.)

**METHOD**

```
 public static void swap(List<?> list,
        int i,
        int j)
```

**Parameters:**

```
list - The list in which to swap elements.
i - the index of one element to be swapped.
j - the index of the other element to be swapped.
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
// first swap the item using  Collections.swap() method
Collections.swap(yourList, firstPosition, positionToSwap);

// than notify your adapter about change in list using  notifyItemMoved() method
YourAdapter.notifyItemMoved(firstPosition, positionToSwap);
```

Comment: do you know how to save that position, because I have done with `Collections.swap()` this works but doesn't save the position when the app is closed and opened again.

Comment: The u need to save that position when user close the app   somewhere  and later when user open the use that saved position

Comment: How can we save that position as you ansewered ?

Comment: @Spritzig how to u want save the position and which position u want to save

Comment: I will add a question in SO and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The way `RecyclerView` works is every time a new item comes on screen it calls your custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` subclass. Adapter has a reference for the dataset you take data for views from and gets passed the `ViewHolder` (the layout of an item) and index into `onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)` to take `dataset[position]` and put the data into `holder.textview.setText(dataset[position])`.

As such, to swap places of elements you have 2 options:

- rearrange data in the initial dataset. Chances are it's an ArrayList<> of some kind and you do `TEMP=dataset[5];ArrayList.remove(TEMP);ArrayList.insert(TEMP,1);` ArrayList will shift everything as required.
- if it is important to keep dataset intact, you can rewrite your adapter, so that it keeps a map of `{ position : dataset_index }` and populates items according to that map. That should be trivial.

And then you have to refresh the data with `adapter.notifyDataSetChaged();`